# Vue: Getting a time in a seconds on page mount and creating hh:mm:ss off of that?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting a `getSecondsUptime` field when a component mounts, saving it to initialData  and then want to increment that each second. However, I am getting an infinite loop warning and hundreds of console logs within seconds.  I can't tell what I am doing wrong.

```
    data() {
        return {
            time: 0,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.time = this.$store.getters['into/getSecondsUptime'];

        setInterval(this.calcTime, 1000)

    },
    
    methods: {
        calcTime: function() {
            console.log('foo');
            this.time = this.time + 1;
            let date = new Date(null);
            date.setSeconds(this.time);
            let result = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling your calcTime function multiple times. Maybe you can change to like this

```
 mounted() {
    this.time = this.$store.getters['into/getSecondsUptime'];
    this.calcTime()
},

methods: {
    calcTime: function() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.time = this.time + 1
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call calcTime by Using window.setInterval which will be called every second. Like below

```
mounted() :{
  this.time = this.$store.getters['into/getSecondsUptime'];
     window.setInterval(() => {
           this.calcTime();
        }, 1000);
},
 methods: {
    calcTime() {
        console.log('foo');
        this.time = this.time + 1;
        let date = new Date(null);
        date.setSeconds(this.time);
        let result = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
        return result;
    }
}
```